# Cross domain ajax call to localhost Web API

Tags: jquery, ajax

I host a Web API on my localhost and I tried to invoke it from a page X on domain www.somedomain.com.

the ajax code on page X looks like this:

```
    $("#pingServer").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/echo",
            data: data,
            type:"POST"
        }).done(function (msg) { $("#display").text("server should have sent the result " + msg); })
        .fail(function (msg) { $("#display").text("error with: " + msg); })
    })
```

When I place the above script in a localhost page, it works.
But from the www.somedomain.com page, it always failed.

Why?

Comment: What error you getting in Console?

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Unless you are hosting the Web API at the same machine as you are displaying your webpage this won't work right? Localhost is the current machine right?

Comment: Web API and the webpage are 2 different machines. localhost is the current machine.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because of the "Same Origin Policy". According to the "Same Origin Policy", from one origin (scheme, host, and port) you can't access the DOM of another origin. In other words, you can't make AJAX calls or connect by WebSockets from one origin to another. There are some ways to solve it, but the 2 major are:

1. Instead of making ajax calls, you can get JS files, so you can import JSON files with data through js. It is called JSONP and JQUERY makes it very simple: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/
2. You can modify the server so it will work although the 2 origins are different. It is called CORS - the W3C spec that allows cross-domain communication. Here is an article that explains this method : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

There are more solutions (like using flash and js - flXHR) but I think these 2 are the simplest and the best solutions.